# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql_connection.h' in release mode

Tags: c++, mysql

Everything goes fine when it is in the debug mode, but when I switch to the release mode and run it, the error came out. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post a `Makefile`, or in case you're building it from an IDE, make sure that under the `Release` configuration the right path to the additional includes is set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am making my project under VS2010, I think I have already include the correct additional includes as I can run it in debug mode, but I am not so sure how to 'Makefile' in windows. Could you please kindly give me some advice?

Comment: Just configure the `Release` version in VS to include the right paths, as your `Debug` version seems to be doing. I cannot tell you how to do it since I am using UNIX but it shouldn't be too hard to find out. Don't bother with `Makefile`s for now.